# How to check if input exists in Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have multiple booth users and I want to check if my username and password exists in a booth field.

Say I login using the username **booth02** and password **password**. I want to return this as true/success.

This is my script:

```
router.post('/getlogin', function (req, res) {
    username = req.body.username;
    password = req.body.password;

    adminlogin = database.ref('booths');

    adminlogin.once('value', function(snapshot){
        var dataSet = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot){

            user = childsnapshot.val().username;
            pass = childsnapshot.val().password;
                if(username == user){
                    req.session.user = childsnapshot.key;
                    req.session.auth = true;
                    return res.status(200).send('Success');
                }else{

                    return res.status(401).send('false');               
                }       
        });

    })
})
```

But the result being returned for my user and pass is the first data which is `username:booth01` and `password:idontknow` .

Is there a way to specifically return the data from Firebase based on my inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
adminlogin.once('value', function(snapshot){
```

to this:

```
adminlogin.orderByChild("username").equalTo(inputname).once('value', function(snapshot){
```

the value `inputname` inside equalTo query will be the input that you entered in the form. Then it will only retrieve data that is related to the name of the user you entered.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo